# How to receive and process JSON in Flask?

Tags: python, json, rest, post, salesforce

I have a Raspberry Pi setup, that needs to be able to receive JSON (from Salesforce). I'm not very familiar with JSON, but I believe this is possible with the REST API.

Anyway, I have downloaded Flask which should capable of doing this for me. When it receives this JSON, I need it to work with a Python script, or work in the same way as this script I already have setup. (This is the script: [here](https://github.com/7ewis/RemotePiControl/blob/master/power.py)). The script remotely controls some power outlets, and I would like Salesforce to be able to turn one one, when triggered. So far, I can control the Power from a web interfaces, using either URL variables, or a POST from a form. This all works well.

I'm just at the last stage, and also the one I have least experience in. What will the JSON Salesforce can send look like? How do I parse this and make it control the Power Outlets via Python?

Comment: Flask supports JSON requests out-of-the-box, see [`request.get_json()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=json#flask.Request.get_json). Presumably Salesforce has documentation on what it fields it'll include in a POST?

Comment: That's why I downloaded it, but I'm not really sure on what the next step would be. Obviously I need to tell Flask what to do with the JSON it receives, but I don't know how to do that. Possibly this? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_json.htm I don't really understand it though, I've never used this before.

Comment: I have no experience with SalesForce, so I have no idea if that document is of any help.

Comment: The fundamental ideas will be the same though won't they? If I move away from Salesforce to something like Zendesk, it should be able to work with that too, although I'd think that the JSON would need to be modified slightly for it to work.

Comment: Each service will have their own API, but they usually work along the same lines, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plan is the following:

[Salesforce] <---> [Flask API] <--> [Raspberry PI]

Salesforce will be creating JSON messages that must be sent to your Flask API that interacts with the raspberry.

I see you have the interaction with Raspberry PI ready so you should create endpoints with Flask to be triggered from the outside.

As an example of a couple of flask endpoints:

```
# define a "power ON api endpoint"
@app.route("/API/v1.0/power-on/<deviceId>",methods=['POST'])
def powerOnDevice(deviceID):
    payload = {}
    #get the device by id somehow
    device = devices.get(deviceId)
    # get some extra parameters 
    # let's say how long to stay on
    params = request.get_json()
    try:

      device.turn_on(params['durationinminutes'])
      payload['success'] = True
      return payload
    except:
      payload['success'] = False
      # add an exception description here
      return payload

# define a "power OFF api endpoint"
@app.route("/API/v1.0/power-off/<deviceId>",methods=['POST'])
def powerOffDevice(deviceID):
    payload = {}
    #get the device by id somehow
    device = devices.get(deviceId)
    try:
      device.turn_off()
      payload['success'] = True
      return payload
    except:
      payload['success'] = False
      # add an exception description here
      return payload
```

In the salesforce side you need to create an object structure to keep track of devices, but I want to show what would be the APEX code needed to send a JSON message to your Flask API.

You'll have a DevicesController class that will have methods that will be triggered from a visualforce page let's say Devices.page

As an example you'll have a method that turns on a device:

```
// this should return something but for the sake of simplicity
public void turnDeviceOn(String externalDeviceId, Integer durationInMinutes){
 # generate json message
 JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
 gen.writeStartObject();
 gen.writeIntegerField('durationinminutes', durationInMinutes);
 gen.writeEndObject();
 # generate http request

 HttpRequest req  = new HttpRequest();
 req.setMethod('POST');
 # this endpoint must be added as a remote endpoint in Salesforce org setup!
 req.setEndpoint('http://yourapiurl/API/v1.0/power-on/'+externalDeviceId);
 req.setBody(gen.getAsString());

 HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);

}
```

Please note that this is a basic Salesforce <--> Flask API example. 
You'll need to add an authentication mechanism and more control on the entire flow.

EDIT:

Since you asked if this can be added to your code [I've forked your repo and integrated that flask endpoint code to your power.py file.](https://github.com/bfagundez/RemotePiControl/blob/master/power.py)
The best solution is that you should put it on a separated class and handle routes on a different file, but can be all together so you get the idea.
You can clone it, install Flask module:

```
pip install flask
```

And execute it with:

```
python power.py
```

Then test the endpoints with:

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost:5000/API/v1.0/power-on/<deviceid>
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the detailed answer. I think I need to learn more about what the code means, so I can properly adapt it to work with my setup. Where could I find out more (at a beginners level)? And I assume that I can't connect this to the .py script I linked? I don't really understand which bits are linked to my existing variables either.

Comment: The best place to start with flask is their [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/). There you should learn how to create a quick hello world and get the general idea.
To start in Salesforce you should look into this [workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook/index.htm).
And yes, your code can be integrated with this, see the edited answer.

Comment: Ok, I have now implemented this, and get a long error message when trying to curl it. This appears when I curl it: [link](http://pastebin.com/EqTs5W6V). And the Pi outputs this: [link](http://pastebin.com/kTNK3BET). What have I done wrong?

Comment: The device id parameter is not read as an integer:

File "/home/pi/FlaskTesting/power.py", line 17, in powerOnDevice
    device = devices[deviceId]

try changing that line for:

device = devices[int(deviceId)]

Comment: Need to import request from flask: from flask import request ([in the quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/), section "Accessing Request Data" this is explained)

Comment: So everything is working as it should, I just need to tell the Pi how to process the JSON?

Comment: Where abouts would I have to put the request code within power.py?

Comment: Json data will be available in "params" dictionary: params = request.get_json().
you should be able to retrieve values from there in power.py.
This thread is getting longer, drop me a line to: b [at] geekymartian.com if you need more help